# Type with single unknown value

Tags: typescript, types

I'm new to TypeScript and wonder if there's a way to do this. I'm writing TypeScript to compile it into JavaScript which will run in an environment in which the `window` object is extended with, among other, a couple of functions which I've declared on the TypeScript side like this (their actual definitions are C++ code, not JavaScript or TypeScript):

```
interface Window {
    getID() : number
    setID(id: number) : void
}
```

That works fine, but in reality, my TypeScript code shouldn't care that these IDs are numbers since it shouldn't be able to add them, increment them or even stringify them. I'd like to forbid things like `setID(123)` or `setID(getID() + getID())`. Basically the only thing I should be able to do is `setID(getID())`.

I think technically, what I need is a bottom type (like `never`), but one that doesn't already exist, so basically create my own never-like type that cannot be assigned to or from `never`. Is this doable? And if not, would `never` be the closest thing?

**Edit:** Just found out that there exists a [proposal for nomial type support](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202), which is exactly what I need.

Comment: `never` should work for you, why do you need a custom type?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I noticed that if I add another couple of functions `getID2` and `setID2`  which also use `never` then I'll be able to do `setID(getID2())` which wouldn't be right if these IDs refer to different type of things internally. So it'd work if I could use something like `getID() : never1` and `getID2() : never2`.

Comment: Well, you can assign `never` to anything, so a custom type won't be of much help - even if you can't assign `never2`  to `never1` you can assign `never` to both (try `const t:number = '1' as never` to see what I mean)

Comment: If your goal is purely for a typescript representation and don't care how it corresponds to the actual JS, this is how I represent NAPI references returned from native node modules: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoqBgN).

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Yeah that makes sense, I guess the point of `never` is to never have an instance of it, since I could also pass `getID()` to everything, which would also be a problem. I guess what I need is a unit type like `null`. Something like `null1` and `null2` where they can't be interchanged with each other or with `null`.

Comment: @chrisbajorin That seems to work! I think it can be simplified a bit like `declare const NativeRefBrand: unique symbol; type MyNativeRef = typeof NativeRefBrand`?

Answer (score 0):

The browser actually doesn't understand typescript, so the typescript code we write gets transpiled to native javascript code for the browser to interpret.

Comment: Sorry I think mentioning the browser was confusing. I edited the question to hopefully be more clear. I'm just trying to limit whatever I'm able to do in TypeScript, before it even gets compiled into JavaScript.